# How to display webcam RTSP feed in web page

Tags: stream, webcam, html, rtsp

I have spent many hours researching how to display an RTSP feed in a web page. I've tried Quicktime (400 bad request), VLC (No plugin to display this content) and Windows Media Player (protocol not supported). I've read many posts and pages tried variations of code in the web page and also looked at streaming servers, but to be honest, I was hoping it wouldn't be that complicated as I would need somewhere to host the server.

In can open the stream in VLC so was surprised when the plugin didn't work. This is the code in the page but the result is (No plugin to display this content) the browser doesn't even ask to download a plugin.

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921"
     codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab"
     width="640" height="480" id="vlc" events="True">
   <param name="Src" value="rtsp://belletout.no-ip.biz:1552/live3.sdp" />
   <param name="ShowDisplay" value="True" />
   <param name="AutoLoop" value="False" />
   <param name="AutoPlay" value="True" />
   <embed id="vlcEmb"  type="application/x-google-vlc-plugin" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" autoplay="yes" loop="no" width="640" height="480"
     target="rtsp://belletout.no-ip.biz:1552/live3.sdp" ></embed>
</OBJECT>
```

I am really surprised that there isn't an easier method to do this unless I am just following examples that aren't appropriate.

Can anyone offer any suggestion as how to display this real RTSP stream from above in a web page? I would be most grateful.

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 0):

You need a live media encoder that can read the webcam feed and than encode it.
try windows media encoder [Windows Media Encoder 9](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17792.)

change your webpage code to use windows media player.
There should be a sample when you install it.